# Given three unit vectors A, B, C, how do I compute the dihedral angle from A to B about C?

Tags: geometry, spheres, spherical-geometry

I have three 3D (Cartesian space) unit vectors that are the vertices of a spherical triangle. How do I compute the rotation angle from A to B about C? Or, put another way, the angle of the spherical triangle at vertex C?

Comment: They are on a plan - what is spherical?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute the planar angle:
$$
\cos(\angle ACB)={(A-C)\cdot(B-C)\over|A-C|\ |B-C|},
$$
where "$\cdot$" represents the dot product.

If you want the spherical angle, then this is the angle between two vectors perpendicular to $C$ and lying in planes $COA$ and $BOA$ (where $O$ is the center of the sphere. Two such vectors are, for instance:
$$
\vec u =(C\times A)\times C,\quad \vec v =(C\times B)\times C.
$$
Spherical angle $\theta$ is then given by
$$
\cos\theta={\vec u\cdot\vec v\over|\vec u|\ |\vec v|}.
$$